# Water flow with plastic and brass pex fittings

Tags: pex, plastic

Is the smaller ID on plastic fittings (for pex) "smaller enough" than brass to have an effect on water flow through the pipes? I'm trying to do everything I can to get the most possible pressure and flow out of my system while I'm re-doing things. Plastic fittings price and lack of reactivity to elements in the well water make sense but I've read that their ID being smaller is a downside. Just wanted to hear from other people before making a decision.

Comment: Sure, it has an effect. If you're concerned why not upsize?

Comment: That's actually my plan, I just want to try to get a feel for how much of a difference brass vs plastic fittings will make. It's a lot more expensive but worth it if the larger ID makes the difference. That's the tough one to know if it will actually be a noticeable or just be so incremental that I would only be able to tell if I meter before/after.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it has an effect.  How could it not?  One benefit to using PEX is that you can make very long runs with a single piece of pipe without any joints.

But if you have a concern about a specific run, then the solution is to upsize that run to a size that will flow what you need at that location.

You have not provided any specifics in your question, so the best answer that can be given is also general.

Comment: Fair enough. It's way too complicated to give a full scenario but it comes down to trying to optimize where possible while not wasting money. I'm really just hoping to get some opinions on the differences but that might require a lot more detail. Thanks for taking the time though.

Answer (score 0):

This gets complicated and messy and also devolves off into marketing (fancy tools to expand the pipe before stuffing it onto fancy fittings with bigger holes...but how much practical difference do those make?)

PEX nominal sizing is larger than PEX actual internal hole sizing, because PEX is a smoothwall, low friction pipe, so it works out. I suspect, to a certain extent, that the plastic fittings are also smoother than their brass counterparts, but I lack interest in trying to establish experimental results for what if any difference that makes. Perhaps there is some data out there?

The more you work PEX like copper or galvanized iron pipe, the less you benefit from this - specifically, most "PEX-centric" plumbing is run as a bunch of "home runs" back to a central manifold (whether purchased as a unit or constructed from fittings/valves) so there's generally a large diameter pipe, a reducing Tee, a valve, some tubing, and a fitting (& possibly an additional valve) and there you are, unless you try to make it act like rigid pipe with a bunch of fittings so it "looks good to an old-school plumber" and costs an arm and a leg in fittings (tubing is cheap by comparison.)

If you run PEX like rigid piping, you have a great deal more fittings in line, so they have more effect on flow.

In most cases, the fixture at the end will be the thing that actually limits flow rate, far more than the piping. There are charts for PEX flow rate .vs. pressure loss, and if you have an abnormally high flow-rate fixture (or one with a very long feed pipe) you would want to consider giving it larger pipe than the typical 1/2" feeder.

Now, if you choose to be like the idiot that took a 1" well feed and "saved money" by shrinking it to 1/2" copper pipe as the main feed for the whole house that I had to upgrade once upon a time, you would expect pressure loss to be an issue. For a typical house, taking a 1" feed, splitting to 3/4" hot and cold mains, and manifolding those mains out to 1/2" fixture feeds works just fine with plastic insert fittings. But the people who want to sell you the fittings with the bigger holes and fancy expander tools to use them will surely tell another tale - but they might be fibbing. If your house is abnormally large or abnormally heavily plumbed you may also need to go bigger, or to use multiple manifolds in different locations to keep the 1/2" runs reasonable.